# HornetQ JMS Topic To Topic Bridge

Tags: jms, hornetq, jms-topic

I'm trying to set up a bridge between two topics.  The idea is this:

- A notification gets posted to a topic on HornetQ server A
- This notification gets sent to a topic on HornetQ server B (over a
  bridge?)
- The client app gets the notification from server B.

The reason I need to do this is, if server B is down, we still want the topic up and eventually delivered to the subscribing servers.

What I need is an example hornetq-configuration.xml and hornetq-jms.xml demonstrating this.  Or am I looking at it the wrong way and there is a better way to do this?

I am using HornetQ 2.2.14.Final.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Topic is not in the core level, but you can do it; follow this link:
https://community.jboss.org/thread/177979