# HornetQ Topic to Topic bridge dropping messages

Tags: jms, hornetq

I'm having troubles setting up a topic bridge in HornetQ ([related to earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15909033/hornetq-jms-topic-to-topic-bridge)).  The idea is this:

- A notification gets posted to a topic on HornetQ server A
- This notification gets sent to a topic on HornetQ server B over a core bridge
- The client app gets the notification from server B.

The problem I'm having now is that if server B is down, the notification gets dropped.  I would use a queue, but we need other subscribers.  I was hoping the bridge would be durable, and messages would make it to the topic on server B.  The way I have it set up is in the hornetq-configuration.xml:

```
<queues>
    <queue name="jms.topic.topic.dat.cds.internal">
        <address>jms.topic.topic.dat.cds.internal</address>
    </queue>
</queues>

<bridges>
    <bridge name="cds-bridge">
        <queue-name>jms.topic.topic.dat.cds.internal</queue-name>
        <forwarding-address>jms.topic.topic.dat.cds</forwarding-address>
        <reconnect-attempts>-1</reconnect-attempts>
        <use-duplicate-detection>true</use-duplicate-detection>
        <static-connectors>
            <connector-ref>remote-connector</connector-ref>
        </static-connectors>
    </bridge>
</bridges>
```

This works only if both servers are up.

Is there a way to make the bridge a durable subscriber?  Is there something I'm missing?

[EDIT - solution] - This works.  The trick is the topic names need to be the same.

```
<queues>
    <queue name="jms.topic.topic.dat.cds">
    <address>jms.topic.topic.dat.cds</address>
</queue>
```

```
<bridges>
<bridge name="cds-bridge">
    <queue-name>jms.topic.topic.dat.cds</queue-name>
    <forwarding-address>jms.topic.topic.dat.cds</forwarding-address>
    <reconnect-attempts>-1</reconnect-attempts>
    <use-duplicate-detection>true</use-duplicate-detection>
    <static-connectors>
        <connector-ref>remote-connector</connector-ref>
    </static-connectors>
</bridge>
</bridges>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say you have the topic jms.topic.SomeTopic

You could create the core-queue as this:

```
<queues>
    <queue name="SomeTopicBridge">
        <address>jms.topic.SomeTopic</address>
    </queue>
</queues>
```

Notice that the address on the Bridge Queue is the same as your Topic name.

Durable Subscriptions on HornetQ are just core-queues on the topic Address.

That way the message will be waiting to be activated until you restart your target server.

If that doesn't answer your question please provide me more detail and I will post edit this answer to address your question in a better way.

On your case, your address should been like this:

```
<queues>
    <queue name="cds-bridge-queue">
        <address>jms.topic.topic.dat.cds</address>
    </queue>
</queues>
```

With this, you will create a core-queue on the topic address, and this core queue will receive all the messages sent to the topic, even if the bridge is offline.

Comment: I think that's what I have above.  The core queue is "jms.topic.topic.dat.cds.internal".  It forwards over a bridge to "jms.topic.topic.dat.cds".  If the bridge is down (i.e. the second server is offline), the topic message is lost.  I'd expect the bridge to function as a durable subscriber and always hold the topic message until the topic on the other side of the bridge was available.

Comment: What is the name of the topic at Source? it seems you got the address wrong

Comment: "jms.topic.topic.dat.cds.internal" is the topic at the source side of the bridge.  "jms.topic.topic.dat.cds" is the topic on the consumer side.

Comment: Note: The xml above was cut from the configuration on the source side.  The destination side is just a topic with no special configuration.

Comment: That's the mistake you had then.. the address of your queue should be jms.topic.topic.dat.cds

Comment: So you're saying we should eliminate the internal queue all-together?  The source queue and consumer side queue should have the same name?

Comment: I have made the XML in such way you can understand the different between queue name and address. The address here must be == your topic address, otherwise you won't have the queue bound correctly to your topic.

Comment: But I would make a distinction that way on the queue bridge.

Comment: Edited the main item.  Is this what you're proposing as the solution?  I'd try it now, but we're rolling with the problem in production for now, and we're patching next week.

Comment: ok, but I think your question is answered. You should probably accept the answer here, and if you need help you should go to the user's forum. SOF is a place to ask questions only.. if you need further help please go to the HornetQ's user forum, this thread is getting too long already